# How to iterate over 3D hashes

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

I have a 3D hash that is being generated using data from a `yaml` file. I need to get the key of each array and join it to it's values in order to display them on a select field on a form.

I tried using `each`, `for...in`, `hash.keys`, `hash.values` and `map` but they return the hashes as one and not separated values

This is the structure of the hash:

```
{
   "AC"=>
       {
         "ACRELANDIA"=>419,
         "ASSIS BRASIL"=>111
       },
    "AL"=>
        {
         "AGUA BRANCA"=>2701,
         "ANADIA"=>2703
        }
}
```

In the end I was hoping for the result to be like this:

```
AC - ACRELANDIA: 419

AC - ASSIS BRASIL: 111
```

... and so on for each city.

Comment: Try a nested loop: `h.each { |k, v| v.each { |kk, vv| puts "#{k} - #{kk}: #{vv}" } }`

Comment: You need to clarify your desired result. Is it text to be displayed or do you wish to return an array or some other object? If the latter, please show a valid Ruby object (e.g., `["AC - ACRELANDIA: 419", ...]`. I suggest you replace ".. and so on for each city." with the two lines from your example. Better to say you have a hash whose values are hashes. A "3D" hash is ill-defined, and even there were agreement on what it meant, I expect it would be a "2D" hash. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below,

```
hash = {
   "AC"=> { "ACRELANDIA"=>419, "ASSIS BRASIL"=>111 },
   "AL"=> { "AGUA BRANCA"=>2701, "ANADIA"=>2703 }
}

hash.flat_map { |x,y| y.map { |z| "#{x} - #{z[0]}: #{z[1]}" } }

# => ["AC - ACRELANDIA: 419", "AC - ASSIS BRASIL: 111", "AL - AGUA BRANCA: 2701", "AL - ANADIA: 2703"]
```

Comment: You can use `flat_map` instead of `map` then `flatten`

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity. Works for hashes of any length (assuming lengths are the same.)

```
hash.
  flat_map { |k, v| [k].product(v.to_a) }.
  map { |e| e.join(' — ') }
#⇒ ["AC — ACRELANDIA — 419",
#   "AC — ASSIS BRASIL — 111",
#   "AL — AGUA BRANCA — 2701",
#   "AL — ANADIA — 2703"]
```

or:

```
hash.
  map { |k, v| [k].product(v.to_a) }.
  flatten(1).
  map { |e| e.join(' — ') }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would prefere [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object)

```
hash = {
   "AC"=> { "ACRELANDIA"=>419, "ASSIS BRASIL"=>111 },
   "AL"=> { "AGUA BRANCA"=>2701, "ANADIA"=>2703 }
}

arr = hsh.each_with_object([]) {|(key, cities), data| cities.each{|name, i| data << "#{key} - #{name}: #{i}"}}
# => ["AC - ACRELANDIA: 419", "AC - ASSIS BRASIL: 111", "AL - AGUA BRANCA: 2701", "AL - ANADIA: 2703"]
```